# Use a "User Macro" in .vcproj RelativePath

Tags: c++, include, visual-c++

Inside [.vcproj files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2208a1f2.aspx) There is a list of all source files in your project.

How can we use a macro to specify the path to a source file?
If we do this:

```
<File
   RelativePath="$(Lib3rdParty)\Qt\qtwinmigrate-2.5-commercial\src\qmfcapp.cpp">
</File>
```

The compiler cannot find the folder:

```
qmfcapp.cpp
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '.\$(lib3rdparty)\qt\qtwinmigrate- 2.5-commercial\src\qmfcapp.cpp': No such file or directory
```

As you can see, our project compiles in several source files from QT. QT lives inside a folder of external libraries, and we don't want hardcode the path from our project to that folder (we have a very large solution)

Comment: Where is $(Lib3rdParty) defined?  Is it defined as an absolute path or is it relative to the project file?  Might try changing RelativePath to AbsolutePath to see what effect it has.

Comment: I didn't think that AbsolutePath would be valid, since it is not in the schema microsoft provides for the project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting an environment variable for 'Lib3rdParty' to the appropriate relative path snippet.

Comment: +1 I hadn't considered environment variables as an option here, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The normal solution is to include the 3rd party includes, libs and source in source control with your own source, so you can track changes to your 3rd party dependencies with your source.

If this is the case, you should be able to use a relative path from each project to the 3rd party source files.

However if your solution is big, and it has project complicated settings you should look at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org), even if you are only building on windows.  CMake enables you to describe your build environment with common settings specified in only one place. More complicated cases can be handled with variables and macros.  Then it generates your visual studio projects, or makefiles from this description.  We introduced it to support a unix port, and now I use it for windows only development too.

VS projects are really clunky to use, opening and closing dialog boxes, setting things for debug and release.  Each project with its own copy of the settings, but mostly the same as all the other projects.

Comment: Thanks for proposing an alternative solution ... We are heavily invested in visual studio project files at the moment, having literally over a hundred seperate active projects. We solve the duplicated settings problem you describe using property sheets, which can be shared between projects.

Answer (score 3):

If you add an existing file from a different drive, you'll notice an absolute path is used.

At least for v8.00, macros do not seem to be expanded. I tried VC, Ant, and OS macro forms - none worked.

There's always the sysinternals' junction option, a mapped network path, or a .lib with a macro spec set into the project/global source, include, and lib paths. Even with the lib package, you should be able to step into the source.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, and welcome to Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

..it should be mentioned that using property sheets gets rid of a lot of the clunkyness though

Comment: Property sheets are indeed invaluable. We use them heavily. The macro in question is defined in one.

Comment: Try setting "Set this macro as an environment variable in the build environment" in the Add User Macro dialog. Worked for me on VS2008.